# how to connect azure storage account from nifi

Tags: azure, apache-nifi

i have created azure storage account(xxx) with 2 container(yyy). when i am trying to list azure blob storage from nifi with the properties set as below:

```
Storage Account Name: xxx
Storage Account Key : xyzzzz
Container name : yyy
```

i am getting the below error message:

```
2017-01-09 16:31:00,873 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.p.a.storage.ListAzureBlobStorage ListAzureBlobStorage[id=783a8d8c-0159-1000-b778-4225cc9a231b] Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec due to processing failure

2017-01-09 16:31:00,873 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.c.t.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask Administratively Yielding ListAzureBlobStorage[id=783a8d8c-0159-1000-b778-4225cc9a231b] due to uncaught Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.

2017-01-09 16:31:00,886 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.c.t.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.ListAzureBlobStorage.performListing(ListAzureBlobStorage.java:338) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.ListAzureBlobStorage.onTrigger(ListAzureBlobStorage.java:187) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) ~[nifi-api-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: An unknown failure occurred : Connection timed out: connect
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109) ~[na:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:119) ~[na:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Is this error related to nifi or azure?

Comment: Looking at the error, I believe it is coming from Azure Storage SDK. I think the machine where this code is running is not able to connect to  Azure Storage.

Comment: how to rectify this issue and connect to azure storage.

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you able to access the Internet from this machine?